# NSPredicate filtering object property that is an array of strings

Tags: arrays, swift, object, properties, filtering

I'm trying to figure out NSPredicate.  The class below is made up data.  I am trying to search an array of objects.  Within an object, I want to search a property that is an array of strings: favoriteTeams.

```
class Person: NSObject {
  let firstName: String
  let nicknames: [String]
  let favoriteTeams: [String]

 init(firstName: String, nicknames: [String], favoriteTeams: [String]) {
    self.firstName = firstName
    self.nicknames = nicknames
    self.favoriteTeams = favoriteTeams
   }
  }

let robert = Person(firstName: "Robert", nicknames: ["Bob", "Robbie"], favoriteTeams: ["Patriots", "Bruins", "Celtics"])  
let tim = Person(firstName: "Timothy", nicknames: ["Timmy", "Tim", "Timbo"], favoriteTeams: ["Patriots", "Montreal", "Celtics"])
let william = Person(firstName: "William", nicknames: ["Will", "Willie", "Bill"], favoriteTeams: ["Jets", "MapleLeafs", "Lakers"])
let stephen = Person(firstName: "Stephan", nicknames: ["Steve", "Stevie"], favoriteTeams: ["Patriots", "Bruins", "Lakers"])

let people = [robert, tim, william, stephen]

let searchTeam = "Patriots"
let robertPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "firstName = 'Robert'")
let teamPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "favoriteTeams CONTAINS[c] %@", searchTeam)

(people as NSArray).filtered(using: robertPredicate)
```

The latter returns the object robert.

```
(people as NSArray).filtered(using: teamPredicate)
```

Corrected the missing "NSPredicate". However, the latter returns what appears to be an empty array.

Comment: You forgot the `NSPredicate` in `let teamPredicate = ...`

Comment: duh... As stated in the above edit, it returns an empty array.

Comment: Try `let teamPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY favoriteTeams = %@", searchTeam)`

Comment: Did you try with `CONTAINS[cd]` instead of just `CONTAINS[c]`?

Comment: Thank you Martin R.  your recommendation worked.  I need to spend some time playing around with NSPredicate.  Can't say I understand the format.  It is pretty cool though.